# Why have two users Thomas and Thomas Ward?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I want to know why have two users, Thomas and Thomas Ward? is there a different people but username almost same?

Comment: @muru No, do not flag, this is nto duplicate.

Comment: You [gave a duplicate answer there](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17587/616451), excepting the parts of [this answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/9251/616451)  that actually answered the question, so you should already know that this is a duplicate question.

Comment: I say this is  not duplicate. Do not flag. If you reflag this, i wil give an attention.

Comment: Just saying this is not a duplicate and then being rude to people does not make this not a duplicate, how about giving a reason why this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usernames are not unique. Anyone can name themselves anything they want, as well as rename themselves whenever they want. As a demonstration, go to [Users](https://askubuntu.com/users) and search for `John`. You'll have hundreds of hits.

The system instead uses user IDs as the authoritative reference. For example, you are user `772394`, and I am user `208574`. Thomas Ward (the mod) has the user ID `10616`. The user ID is a part of the URL of a user account:

[image: An Ask Ubuntu URL for my user, with the user ID in a red box.]

In theory, it becomes possible then for a user to [have the same name](https://askubuntu.com/users/161269/seth) as [a moderator](https://askubuntu.com/users/44179/seth). To prevent cases of mistaken identity, moderators are distinguished by the ♦ by their name <s>as well as the aura of power emanating from their user cards</s>.

The moderator [Thomas Ward](https://askubuntu.com/users/10616/thomas-ward) will have their diamond, and will look something like this on the site:

[image: Thomas Ward, in the flesh? User card?]

Otherwise, usernames are almost a free-for-all. Diamonds, as well as some other characters, may not be used in usernames (for obvious reasons).